# Using `inject` to add `value * qty` in a hash

Tags: ruby, hash, iteration, inject

I have the following hash:

```
{#<Dish:0x007fb45505ff30 @dish={:name=>"Chicken Pie", :price=>4.5}> => 2}
```

In order to add up the `price * qty` (which is the `2` at the end), I am using the code:

```
@order.map { |item, qty| item.price * qty }.inject(:+)
```

which returns a value of `9`.

Is there anyway to rewrite this code to something along the line of:

```
@order.inject(0) { |item, qty| item.price * qty }
```

Comment: Be careful using your custom object as a hash key.  Have you implemented a hash and == or eql? method?

Comment: If you were using Rails, you could use `sum` like `@order.sum { |item, qty| item.price * qty }`

Comment: @potashin if this is Rails, then there is probably a DB behind it and you can easily sum this in the DB without even loading the records.

Comment: @pascalbetz: not necessarily, it can be remote API or whatever you can imagine, which result can be transformed to something, that can be handled by `Enumerable`.

Comment: Good point. So "If it is AR" then you can do it in the DB.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample:

```
class Item
  attr_reader :name, :price
  def initialize(name, price)
    @name = name
    @price = price
  end
end

data = {Item.new('Book', 10) => 2, Item.new('Sandwich', 33) => 1}
sum = data.inject(0) do |total, (item, amount)|
  total + item.price * amount
end

puts "Total: #{sum}"
```

Take into account the comment by Keith: custom objects as hash keys might not work as expected, unless you've taken care of identity.

Answer (score 1):

```
@order.inject(0){|n, (item, qty)| n + item.price * qty}
```

Answer (score 0):

What would you want to happen if there was more than one dish in this hash? What's the actual behaviour you want?

If you just want to know the total price of a single item hash, and use your inject example, you need to remember you're trying to inject a hash, which needs memo and element block arguments - and in your case, the element is going to be the key value pair of each item in your hash.

For example:

```
@order.inject(0) { |item, qty| puts item.inspect }
```

and see what you get. Something along the lines of `[#<Dish:0x007fb45505ff30 @dish={:name=>"Chicken Pie", :price=>4.5}>, 2]` I guess.

So capture that array of key value into two other args.

```
@order.inject(0) { |memo, (item, qty)| memo + (item.price * qty) }
```